# How to access x64 hardware directly without Hardware Abstraction Layers?

Tags: c++, c, linux, assembly, hardware

I have kind of a weird question but I am interested in this topic.

Is there any possiblity to access the hardware of a current x64 based computer directly without going with some sort of HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer) or the pendant of other operating systems (udev, upower, ...)? And I am not talking about developing a certain device driver, instead of that I am talking about a simple "Hello World" programming with C or assembler or something like that.

I am aware of the fact that things like multiple cpu cores and multithreading and so on make this kind of programming some sort of senseless for the most common cases. However, I am interested in knowing if it is possible at all and if so, how you could do it?

My focus lies on Linux based operating systems. And as far as I know it's not possible on Microsoft based operating systems since 98 / ME

Many thanks for your effort in advance & best regards,
B.

Comment: Is `int     0x80` a HAL? Protected mode operating systems run in *protected mode*; only the operating system is allowed direct hardware access. To start with, where is your `"Hello World"` going to display?

Comment: *Which* hardware do you want to access directly? You can easily access things like cpu-register (which are, after all, hardware), but accessing something like the MMU is privileged.

Comment: Short answer: no. It would defeat the point of having an operating system protecting your resources if you could just do that. That said, you can have a process running with the necessary privileges access physical memory (after you ask the OS to map it into your address space) and so you could theoretically print something into VGA text memory if you are using a console.

Comment: ad where) It's gonna be display using a console.

ad which hardware) It'd like to do something like mov-commands in assembly, so I'd like to access CPU and memory directly. I'm not sure if I need access to certain I/O ports to show something on a console.  

ad HAL) As far as I know even the operating systems don't access the hardware directly anymore. They access the hardware using something like a HAL to enable max portability. If I write a default assembly program and I am using mov-commands I'm working with HAL instead of accessing the CPU directly. But I want to access the CPU directly.

Comment: @user4587483: If you're using a `mov %reg, (memory)`, you're indeed dealing with virtual addresses in usermode, which you could consider "Hardware abstraction". But if you're using `mov %reg, %reg`, you're accessing hardware directly, as far as the ISA is concerned.

Comment: If you want to access hardware directly they you might consider writing a device drive. They are just ordinary programs but obviously run in a rather different environment. There is nothing magical about them, but obviously you'd need to learn the requirements of making one.

Comment: Sure, but not from a user-space process in Linux or Windows.  Write your own 64bit OS / free-standing program that writes to VGA memory in 64bit mode.  I assume that must be possible, because memory is just memory.  You won't be able to use an 16bit BIOS APIs from 64bit mode, and you'll need some code to switch to 64bit mode after a bootloader loads your code.  You could start with the Linux kernel code, and add your own stuff just after it switches to 64bit mode in the x86 startup code.  (IDK where that is exactly, I just know it exists).

Answer (score 2):

No, you wouldn't be able to do this in any language. The reason is rather simple - in any modern architecture user programms are running in so-called protected mode. What it means (among other things) is that you do not have access to real memory - instead, CPU together with OS translate memory addresses your program is using to something else.

In order to communicate with hardware you really need to access the memory region which is used by this hardware - and this is totally impossible in protected mode.

Comment: So it's not possible to run a programm written in whatever language in real mode under Linux or Windows or something like that? 

Furthermore: is it called real mode under Linux too or it is it a Windows-specific term?

Comment: @user4587483, yes, *real mode* is a CPU-specific term, not OS-specific term. And yes, you can't switch from protected mode to real mode from ring 3, where your application is normally executing.

Comment: You can of course switch to real mode from protected mode, but not from ring 3 :) Also it would just be easier to boot to real mode then.

Comment: @Jester, true enough for ring 3. I will update. As for booting, I assume, it would kinda mean you are not the app anymore, but an OS :)

Comment: OK thank you very much for your quick answers.

But real mode is a 32bit-thing, isn't it? The 64bit-pendant is Long Mode as far as I know. And I guess the same goes for long mode on x64 as for the real mode on x86, right?

Comment: @user4587483, not sure what you are actually asking about, sorry. Are you just asking about naming for different CPU modes? That's pretty straightforward.